# Before their disastrous demise, how many missions did Challenger and Columbia fly?

Tags: nasa, space-shuttle

I always grew up thinking that both of those shuttles only flew in one mission and never made it back home. Now, I found evidence that that's not the case.

Comment: Wikipedia tells us how many flights each made before destruction in the intro to the articles....

Comment: You should include your current state of research about those evidences so that we can add relevant links and references you don't know.

Comment: Columbia was actually the first Shuttle to fly ever, and flew long after Challenger.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Challenger: 10 launches

Columbia: 28 launches

Source: spreadsheet I kept throughout my career

[image]

Edit:

Here is an ASCII version of the spreadsheet, created since OP is visually impaired.

```
+----+----------+------+------------+------------+------+------------+-----------+------+------------+----------+------+------------+-----------+-----+------------+
|    |          |      |            |            |      |            | SEQ       | FLT  |            |          |      |            |           |     |            |
| 39 |          |      |            |            |      |            | 133       | 133  | 2/24/2011  |          |      |            |           |     |            |
| 38 |          |      |            |            |      |            | 131       | 131  | 4/5/2010   |          |      |            |           |     |            |
| 37 |          |      |            |            |      |            | 128       | 128  | 8/28/2009  |          |      |            |           |     |            |
| 36 |          |      |            |            |      |            | 125       | 119  | 3/15/2009  |          |      |            |           |     |            |
| 35 |          |      |            |            |      |            | 123       | 124  | 5/31/2008  |          |      |            |           |     |            |
| 34 |          |      |            |            |      |            | 120       | 120  | 10/23/2007 | SEQ      | FLT  |            |           |     |            |
| 33 |          |      |            |            |      |            | 117       | 116  | 12/9/2006  | 135      | 135  | 7/8/2011   |           |     |            |
| 32 |          |      |            |            |      |            | 115       | 121  | 7/4/2006   | 132      | 132  | 5/14/2010  |           |     |            |
| 31 |          |      |            |            |      |            | 114       | 114  | 7/26/2005  | 129      | 129  | 11/16/2009 |           |     |            |
| 30 |          |      |            |            |      |            | 106       | 105  | 8/10/2001  | 126      | 125  | 5/11/2009  |           |     |            |
| 29 | SEQ      | FLT  |            |            |      |            | 103       | 102  | 3/8/2001   | 121      | 122  | 2/7/2008   |           |     |            |
| 28 | 113      | 107  | 1/16/2003  |            |      |            | 100       | 92   | 10/11/2000 | 118      | 117  | 6/8/2007   |           |     |            |
| 27 | 108      | 109  | 3/1/2002   |            |      |            | 96        | 103  | 12/19/1999 | 116      | 115  | 8/28/2006  |           |     |            |
| 26 | 95       | 93   | 7/23/1999  |            |      |            | 94        | 96   | 5/27/1999  | 111      | 112  | 10/7/2002  | SEQ       | FLT |            |
| 25 | 90       | 90   | 4/17/1998  |            |      |            | 92        | 95   | 10/29/1998 | 109      | 110  | 4/19/2002  | 134       | 134 | 5/16/2011  |
| 24 | 88       | 87   | 11/19/1997 |            |      |            | 91        | 91   | 8/2/1998   | 105      | 104  | 7/12/2001  | 130       | 130 | 2/7/2010   |
| 23 | 85       | 94   | 7/1/1997   |            |      |            | 86        | 85   | 8/7/1997   | 102      | 98   | 2/7/2001   | 127       | 127 | 7/15/2009  |
| 22 | 83       | 83   | 4/4/1997   |            |      |            | 82        | 82   | 2/11/1997  | 99       | 106  | 9/8/2000   | 124       | 126 | 11/10/2008 |
| 21 | 80       | 80   | 11/19/1996 |            |      |            | 70        | 70   | 7/13/1995  | 98       | 101  | 5/19/2000  | 122       | 123 | 3/11/2008  |
| 20 | 78       | 78   | 8/20/1996  |            |      |            | 67        | 63   | 2/3/1995   | 87       | 86   | 9/25/1997  | 119       | 118 | 8/8/2007   |
| 19 | 75       | 75   | 2/22/1996  |            |      |            | 64        | 64   | 9/9/1994   | 84       | 84   | 5/15/1997  | 112       | 113 | 11/23/2002 |
| 18 | 72       | 73   | 10/20/1995 |            |      |            | 60        | 60   | 2/3/1994   | 81       | 81   | 1/12/1997  | 110       | 111 | 6/5/2002   |
| 17 | 63       | 65   | 7/8/1994   |            |      |            | 57        | 51   | 9/12/1993  | 79       | 79   | 9/16/1996  | 107       | 108 | 12/5/2001  |
| 16 | 61       | 62   | 3/4/1994   |            |      |            | 54        | 56   | 4/8/1993   | 76       | 76   | 3/22/1996  | 104       | 100 | 4/19/2001  |
| 15 | 58       | 58   | 10/18/1993 |            |      |            | 52        | 53   | 12/2/1992  | 73       | 74   | 11/12/1995 | 101       | 97  | 11/30/2000 |
| 14 | 55       | 55   | 4/26/1993  |            |      |            | 45        | 42   | 1/22/1992  | 69       | 71   | 6/27/1995  | 97        | 99  | 2/11/2000  |
| 13 | 51       | 52   | 10/22/1992 |            |      |            | 43        | 48   | 9/12/1991  | 66       | 66   | 11/3/1994  | 93        | 88  | 12/4/1998  |
| 12 | 48       | 50   | 6/25/1992  |            |      |            | 40        | 39   | 4/28/1991  | 49       | 46   | 7/31/1992  | 89        | 89  | 1/22/1998  |
| 11 | 41       | 40   | 6/5/1991   | SEQ        | FLT  |            | 36        | 41   | 10/6/1990  | 46       | 45   | 3/24/1992  | 77        | 77  | 5/19/1996  |
| 10 | 38       | 35   | 12/2/1990  | 25         | 51-L | 1/28/1986  | 35        | 31   | 4/24/1990  | 44       | 44   | 11/24/1991 | 74        | 72  | 1/11/1996  |
|  9 | 33       | 32   | 1/9/1990   | 22         | 61-A | 10/30/1985 | 32        | 33   | 11/22/1989 | 42       | 43   | 8/2/1991   | 71        | 69  | 9/7/1995   |
|  8 | 30       | 28   | 8/8/1989   | 19         | 51-F | 7/28/1985  | 28        | 29   | 3/13/1989  | 39       | 37   | 4/5/1991   | 68        | 67  | 3/2/1995   |
|  7 | 24       | 61-C | 1/12/1986  | 17         | 51-B | 4/29/1985  | 26        | 26   | 9/2/1988   | 37       | 38   | 11/15/1990 | 65        | 68  | 9/30/1994  |
|  6 | 9        | 9    | 11/28/1983 | 13         | 41-G | 10/5/1984  | 20        | 51-I | 8/27/1985  | 34       | 36   | 2/28/1990  | 62        | 59  | 4/9/1994   |
|  5 | 5        | 5    | 11/11/1982 | 11         | 41-C | 4/6/1984   | 18        | 51-G | 6/17/1985  | 31       | 34   | 10/18/1989 | 59        | 61  | 12/2/1993  |
|  4 | 4        | 4    | 6/27/1982  | 10         | 41-B | 2/3/1984   | 16        | 51-D | 4/12/1985  | 29       | 30   | 5/4/1989   | 56        | 57  | 6/21/1993  |
|  3 | 3        | 3    | 3/22/1982  | 8          | 8    | 8/30/1983  | 15        | 51-C | 1/24/1985  | 27       | 27   | 12/2/1988  | 53        | 54  | 1/13/1993  |
|  2 | 2        | 2    | 11/12/1981 | 7          | 7    | 6/18/1983  | 14        | 51-A | 11/7/1984  | 23       | 61-B | 11/26/1985 | 50        | 47  | 9/12/1992  |
|  1 | 1        | 1    | 4/12/1981  | 6          | 6    | 4/4/1983   | 12        | 41-D | 8/30/1984  | 21       | 51-J | 10/3/1985  | 47        | 49  | 5/7/1992   |
|    | Columbia |      |            | Challenger |      |            | Discovery |      |            | Atlantis |      |            | Endeavour |     |            |
|    | OV-102   |      |            | OV-099     |      |            | OV-103    |      |            | OV-104   |      |            | OV-105    |     |            |
+----+----------+------+------------+------------+------+------------+-----------+------+------------+----------+------+------------+-----------+-----+------------+
```

And another version using the the new table format. I left the ASCII table in because I'm not sure this is really an improvement.

| ndx | SEQ | FLT | Date | SEQ | FLT | Date | SEQ | FLT | Date | SEQ | FLT | Date | SEQ | FLT | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 39 |  |  |  |  |  |  | 133 | 133 | 2/24/2011 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 38 |  |  |  |  |  |  | 131 | 131 | 4/5/2010 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 37 |  |  |  |  |  |  | 128 | 128 | 8/28/2009 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 36 |  |  |  |  |  |  | 125 | 119 | 3/15/2009 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 35 |  |  |  |  |  |  | 123 | 124 | 5/31/2008 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 34 |  |  |  |  |  |  | 120 | 120 | 10/23/2007 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 33 |  |  |  |  |  |  | 117 | 116 | 12/9/2006 | 135 | 135 | 7/8/2011 |  |  |  |
| 32 |  |  |  |  |  |  | 115 | 121 | 7/4/2006 | 132 | 132 | 5/14/2010 |  |  |  |
| 31 |  |  |  |  |  |  | 114 | 114 | 7/26/2005 | 129 | 129 | 11/16/2009 |  |  |  |
| 30 |  |  |  |  |  |  | 106 | 105 | 8/10/2001 | 126 | 125 | 5/11/2009 |  |  |  |
| 29 |  |  |  |  |  |  | 103 | 102 | 3/8/2001 | 121 | 122 | 2/7/2008 |  |  |  |
| 28 | 113 | 107 | 1/16/2003 |  |  |  | 100 | 92 | 10/11/2000 | 118 | 117 | 6/8/2007 |  |  |  |
| 27 | 108 | 109 | 3/1/2002 |  |  |  | 96 | 103 | 12/19/1999 | 116 | 115 | 8/28/2006 |  |  |  |
| 26 | 95 | 93 | 7/23/1999 |  |  |  | 94 | 96 | 5/27/1999 | 111 | 112 | 10/7/2002 |  |  |  |
| 25 | 90 | 90 | 4/17/1998 |  |  |  | 92 | 95 | 10/29/1998 | 109 | 110 | 4/19/2002 | 134 | 134 | 5/16/2011 |
| 24 | 88 | 87 | 11/19/1997 |  |  |  | 91 | 91 | 8/2/1998 | 105 | 104 | 7/12/2001 | 130 | 130 | 2/7/2010 |
| 23 | 85 | 94 | 7/1/1997 |  |  |  | 86 | 85 | 8/7/1997 | 102 | 98 | 2/7/2001 | 127 | 127 | 7/15/2009 |
| 22 | 83 | 83 | 4/4/1997 |  |  |  | 82 | 82 | 2/11/1997 | 99 | 106 | 9/8/2000 | 124 | 126 | 11/10/2008 |
| 21 | 80 | 80 | 11/19/1996 |  |  |  | 70 | 70 | 7/13/1995 | 98 | 101 | 5/19/2000 | 122 | 123 | 3/11/2008 |
| 20 | 78 | 78 | 8/20/1996 |  |  |  | 67 | 63 | 2/3/1995 | 87 | 86 | 9/25/1997 | 119 | 118 | 8/8/2007 |
| 19 | 75 | 75 | 2/22/1996 |  |  |  | 64 | 64 | 9/9/1994 | 84 | 84 | 5/15/1997 | 112 | 113 | 11/23/2002 |
| 18 | 72 | 73 | 10/20/1995 |  |  |  | 60 | 60 | 2/3/1994 | 81 | 81 | 1/12/1997 | 110 | 111 | 6/5/2002 |
| 17 | 63 | 65 | 7/8/1994 |  |  |  | 57 | 51 | 9/12/1993 | 79 | 79 | 9/16/1996 | 107 | 108 | 12/5/2001 |
| 16 | 61 | 62 | 3/4/1994 |  |  |  | 54 | 56 | 4/8/1993 | 76 | 76 | 3/22/1996 | 104 | 100 | 4/19/2001 |
| 15 | 58 | 58 | 10/18/1993 |  |  |  | 52 | 53 | 12/2/1992 | 73 | 74 | 11/12/1995 | 101 | 97 | 11/30/2000 |
| 14 | 55 | 55 | 4/26/1993 |  |  |  | 45 | 42 | 1/22/1992 | 69 | 71 | 6/27/1995 | 97 | 99 | 2/11/2000 |
| 13 | 51 | 52 | 10/22/1992 |  |  |  | 43 | 48 | 9/12/1991 | 66 | 66 | 11/3/1994 | 93 | 88 | 12/4/1998 |
| 12 | 48 | 50 | 6/25/1992 |  |  |  | 40 | 39 | 4/28/1991 | 49 | 46 | 7/31/1992 | 89 | 89 | 1/22/1998 |
| 11 | 41 | 40 | 6/5/1991 |  |  |  | 36 | 41 | 10/6/1990 | 46 | 45 | 3/24/1992 | 77 | 77 | 5/19/1996 |
| 10 | 38 | 35 | 12/2/1990 | 25 | 51-L | 1/28/1986 | 35 | 31 | 4/24/1990 | 44 | 44 | 11/24/1991 | 74 | 72 | 1/11/1996 |
| 9 | 33 | 32 | 1/9/1990 | 22 | 61-A | 10/30/1985 | 32 | 33 | 11/22/1989 | 42 | 43 | 8/2/1991 | 71 | 69 | 9/7/1995 |
| 8 | 30 | 28 | 8/8/1989 | 19 | 51-F | 7/28/1985 | 28 | 29 | 3/13/1989 | 39 | 37 | 4/5/1991 | 68 | 67 | 3/2/1995 |
| 7 | 24 | 61-C | 1/12/1986 | 17 | 51-B | 4/29/1985 | 26 | 26 | 9/2/1988 | 37 | 38 | 11/15/1990 | 65 | 68 | 9/30/1994 |
| 6 | 9 | 9 | 11/28/1983 | 13 | 41-G | 10/5/1984 | 20 | 51-I | 8/27/1985 | 34 | 36 | 2/28/1990 | 62 | 59 | 4/9/1994 |
| 5 | 5 | 5 | 11/11/1982 | 11 | 41-C | 4/6/1984 | 18 | 51-G | 6/17/1985 | 31 | 34 | 10/18/1989 | 59 | 61 | 12/2/1993 |
| 4 | 4 | 4 | 6/27/1982 | 10 | 41-B | 2/3/1984 | 16 | 51-D | 4/12/1985 | 29 | 30 | 5/4/1989 | 56 | 57 | 6/21/1993 |
| 3 | 3 | 3 | 3/22/1982 | 8 | 8 | 8/30/1983 | 15 | 51-C | 1/24/1985 | 27 | 27 | 12/2/1988 | 53 | 54 | 1/13/1993 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 | 11/12/1981 | 7 | 7 | 6/18/1983 | 14 | 51-A | 11/7/1984 | 23 | 61-B | 11/26/1985 | 50 | 47 | 9/12/1992 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 4/12/1981 | 6 | 6 | 4/4/1983 | 12 | 41-D | 8/30/1984 | 21 | 51-J | 10/3/1985 | 47 | 49 | 5/7/1992 |
|  | Columbia |  |  | Challenger |  |  | Discovery |  |  | Atlantis |  |  | Endeavour |  |  |
|  | OV-102 |  |  | OV-099 |  |  | OV-103 |  |  | OV-104 |  |  | OV-105 |  |  |

Comment: Cool one. Just for completeness, would you explain what do the colours mean?

Comment: Blue background = pre Challenger failure, green background = between the failures, orange background = post Columbia failure.

Comment: I am totally blind. Can you describe or edit the image you included in your source? Thanks!

Comment: It shows five columns, one for each of the space-worthy Orbiters. There is an entry in each column for each launch of the Orbiter showing the sequential shuttle program launch number, the mission designation, and the date. I have read that it's difficult to post tables in stack exchange answers but I will see if I can do it so that you can read the info.

Comment: @HeavenlyHarmony I have updated the answer to include an ASCII version of the table.

Answer (score 2):

To summarize Organic Marble's table:

- [*Challenger*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Shuttle_Challenger) flew 9 successful missions between April 1983 and November 1985 before its loss.
- [*Columbia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Shuttle_Columbia) flew 27 successful missions between April 1981 and March 2002 before its loss.
- [*Discovery*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Shuttle_Discovery) flew the most of any of the orbiters, 39 missions from August 1984 to March 2011.
- [*Atlantis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Shuttle_Atlantis) flew 33 missions, including the final mission of shuttle program, from October 1985 to July 2011.
- [*Endeavour*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Shuttle_Endeavour) was the last shuttle built, and flew 25 missions from May 1992 to June 2011.
- [*Enterprise*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Shuttle_Enterprise) was built for atmospheric tests and never flew in space. It made five "free flight" [approach-and-landing tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approach_and_Landing_Tests) as a glider in 1977.