# What was the last US manned space program?

Tags: spacecraft, space-shuttle

I needed some info for a project.
I tried some Google search but couldn't find an answer.
US decommissioned it's space shuttle in 2011. Columbia disaster was in Feb 1, 2003. We're there any manned mission between that period?
And if available, what number of US astronauts have used soyuz in that period?

Comment: Here you go: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Space_Shuttle_missions

Comment: List of missions at a glance here: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/25405/before-their-disastrous-demise-how-many-missions-did-challenger-and-columbia-fl

Comment: There were US astronauts in the ISS after 2011.

Comment: Their participation in the ISS are manned space programs of the participating countries, US included, regardless of who provides the transport up/down, so their participation in ISS continues to be a current US manned space program. Perhaps you mean last manned space launch by a US launch system, which would be the [last Space Shuttle flight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STS-135)

Answer (score 5):

Space Shuttle was the last US crewed launcher program, and we've been relying on Soyuz to bring astronauts to ISS since 2011. Wikipedia has a [complete list of shuttle flights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Space_Shuttle_missions).

There was a 30-month hiatus after the Columbia disaster but flights resumed with mission STS-114 in 2005, continuing through STS-135 (26 flights).

Likewise, there's a [list of Soyuz missions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Soyuz_missions), complete with their crews -- conveniently flagged by nationality!